# How to embed table rows in div or something else and do not broke jQuery fadeIn function?

Tags: jquery

I have a very specific problem.

I would like to insert a specific code using fadeIn, fadeOut functions, but it is not working if I am using tr and td tags embeded in div tag.

I have this code for JS part:

```
var registrationPart = $('div.registration-part');
var loginPart = $('div.login-part');

$('span.logreg.log').click ( function () {

                registrationPart.fadeOut("fast");
                loginPart.fadeIn("slow");

}
```

And this in html:

```
<table class="table">
    <div class="registration-part">
        <tr>
                  <td>registration</td>
            </tr>
    </div>
    <div class="login-part">
        <tr>
                  <td>login</td>
            </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

So the fadeIn, fadeOut is not working if there are tr,td tags inside of divs. If I replace them with divs or spans everything works fine.

Is there a way how to leave tr,td , so I don't need to make specific stylesheet for divs so it will look like tr,td.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you have is **invalid HTML**, so it's not rendering how you expect it to. You can't put a `<div>` inside a `<table>` and have it contain `<tr>` elements; you can include a `<div>` inside a `<td>` element but that doesn't really help you.

If you want to define separate sections of a table, use the `<tbody>` tag:

HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody class="registration-part">
        <tr>
            <td>registration</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="login-part">
        <tr>
            <td>login</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
var registrationPart = $('tbody.registration-part');
var loginPart = $('tbody.login-part');

$('span.logreg.log').click ( function () {
    registrationPart.fadeOut("fast");
    loginPart.fadeIn("slow");
}
```

If you take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/vwg6r/) with your original HTML and inspect the table with Firebug, you'll notice that the `<div>` elements are **before** the table and empty, and don't include the rows that you wanted them to.

Comment: i was thinking that you can have only 1 tbody, but it seems taht ist is not true and your solution works great ;)

Comment: @johnnyb3000 You can only have at most one `<thead>` and one `<tfoot>` (and they need to come before any `<tbody>` elements), but you can have as many `<tbody>` elements as you require.

Answer (score 0):

Place div inside the table cell. See here http://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/

Comment: it doesn't help fadeIn, fadeOut is still not working, like it has no effect on tr and  td

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `<div>` tags inside your table? You should drive your `<tr>` tags instead.

Please, try this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NcNSU/)

Have a nice day

Comment: Please, read my description one more time. Your example is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selector').click(function () {
    $('.registration-part').parent().find('td:first').fadeOut('fast');
    $('.login-part').parent().find('td:last').fadeIn('slow');
});
```